# Stored Procedures With optional parameters MVC4

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a stored procedure with some optional parameters.....I pass a type parameter and depending on that i invoke the appropriate query.
Following is my query

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_InsertInfo]
@login_id varchar(500)=null,
@login_name varchar(200)=null,
@handler_name varchar(500)=null,
@city varchar(100)=null,
@email varchar(500)=null,
@img_url_http varchar(max)=null,
@img_url_https varchar(max)=null,
@token varchar(500)=null,
@login_type varchar(2)=null
as
begin
if(@login_type='F')
//code goes here
else
//code goes here
end
```

And here is the way i am calling it from my controller

```
using (Entities dbContext = new Entities())
                    {

                        var parameters = new SqlParameter[7];
                        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "login_id", Value = objUser.Id };
                        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "login_name", Value = objUser.Name };
                        parameters[2] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "handler_name", Value = objUser.ScreenName };
                        parameters[3] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "img_url_http", Value = objUser.ProfileImageUrl };
                        parameters[4] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "img_url_https", Value = objUser.ProfileImageUrlHttps };
                        parameters[5] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "token", Value = accessToken.Token };
                        parameters[6] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "login_type", Value = "T" };
                        List<userInfo> objUserInfo = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<userInfo>("usp_InsertInfo @login_id,@login_name,@handler_name,@img_url_http,@img_url_https,@token,@login_type", parameters).ToList();
                    }
```

But when i check the values in Database the values are messed up...

In img_url_http i get the token value img_url_https i get the type value and so on.

M confused like where m i going wrong or wether MVC4 doesnot support null parameters.
Or please help me with the proper way of calling the stored procedure through MVC4 with optional parameters

I want to run this code with the optional parameters and execute the store procedure and return the results depending upon the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void CallAProcedure(int required, int? optional)
{
    string connectionstring = "connection string here.";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cm.CommandText = "AProcedure";
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Required", 1);

            if (optional.HasValue)
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Optional", optional.Value);

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
}
```